Derek the Differentiable Dinosaur
I’ve come across several fond references to some semi-published lecture notes from Warwick in the 80s, by Bill Breckon (and, in some mentions, I. Harrison), Differentiating functions of lots of variables, starring Derek the Differentiable Dinosaur.  Unfortunately I can’t find a digital copy, and the only physical copy I can locate is in the British Library, which I won’t be near for a while.  Does anyone have an online source or digital copy of these notes?
The notes are referenced for instance in Welbourne 1985, As any Brontosaurus can tell you, it’s not a paradox, Eureka, vol. 45 (the sometimes rather good journal of the Cambridge student mathematical society), and listed in the British Library catalogue here.  They’re discussed in this comment thread on The Register:

When I went to Warwick uni in the early 90s, one of our Maths profs wrote his own book for the course -- "Derek the differentiable dinosaur". It was available for about 5 quid which covered photocopyiong charges, or we were free to photocopy someone else's copy if we wanted to, since it was all public domain.
This guy was very, very popular.


The cited Eureka article is by Eddy Welbourne.  His email address is given in obfuscated form at  https://www.chaos.org.uk/~eddy/.  Perhaps he could help.

I don't see a research mathematics angle in this question; this looks like undergraduate teaching material.

@FedericoPoloni: Indeed, I’m aware this is a bit borderline here, and I also considered posting at Math Educators Stack Exchange, where it fits the basic site brief more clearly.  But it fits the community expertise and interests here much better (that site is more concerned with, and better at, questions of current pedagogy), and questions on research-adjacent literature have been considered on-topic here in the past, provided they’re substantially of interest to research mathematicians, which I felt this would be!

You repeated a couple of times that you feel this is "research-adjacent" and "of interest to research mathematicians", but you did not provide arguments why. Is there a research angle that is not apparent to me, or is your argument that this should be interesting to research mathematicians just because many research mathematicians also have to teach calculus?

I remember "Derek", but it was written (just) before (La)TeX and well before the Web. So I  doubt very much that there is a digital or even physical copy available other than by paying one of the university libraries to scan it for you, which may cost less than you imagine.
